# Check Null value in LINQ where clause on Char DB column

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a general question about getting results from DB where a particular column is `null`.

Example:

Table `"Student"`

```
no        int           //1,2,3 etc..
name      varchar(50)   //xxx, yyy etc...
isMinor   char(36)      //'Y' OR 'N' OR NULL
```

now when i have to get rows where `isMinor` is null then we have to use the following query

```
SELECT* FROM Student WHERE isMinor IS NULL
```

I need the equivalent query in `LINQ`. I tried `DBNull.Value` and compared with `null` tried `String.Empty` but nothing working out.

```
var result = from s in db.Student where s.isMinor == null Select s
```

Result: Returns 0 records even there are some records in DB will `null` value in `isMinor` column

```
var result = from s in db.Student where s.isMinor == DBNull.Value Select s
```

Result:

> Error: "unexpected type code: dbnull"

```
var result = from s in db.Student where (Object)s.isMinor == DBNull.Value Select s
```

Result:

> Error: "unexpected type code: dbnull"

```
var result = from s in db.Student where String.isNullOREmpty(s.isMinor) Select s
```

Result: Returns 0 records even there are some records in DB will `null` value in `isMinor` column

Is there anything am missing in this query construction?

Comment: Can you show your `Student` class?

Comment: Are you certain you;re querying the same database? What values for `s.isMinor` are you getting in your results? It is getting mapped to a non-nullable `bool` property?

Comment: When nothing else works I sometimes use following : var result = from s in db.Student where ((string)s.isMinor).Length == 0 Select s

Comment: Is there an error message, or does it just not behave as expected?

Comment: Updated the result from the queries

Comment: Verify your Linq-to-Sql column mapping. If `isMinor` is mapped to `String` your query using `s.isMinor == null` should work.